# How to get last day of current month via Ni-Fi expression language?

Tags: apache-nifi

As far as I understood there's only now() function available in ni-fi expression language to get time. I can easily get 1st day of each month since it is a constant, but how can I get last day of a current month since it varies from month to month?

Thank you beforehand!

Comment: This is how you get the last day of the previous month:  `${now():format("yyyy-MM"):toDate("yyyy-MM"):toNumber():minus(86400000):format("yyyy-MM-dd")}` So far, I don't know how to get the current month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
${now():format("yyyy-MM-32"):toDate("yyyy-MM-dd"):format("yyyy-MM"):toDate("yyyy-MM"):minus(86400000)}
//^now  ^next month          ^to date             ^1st of next month                  ^minus 1 day
```

nifi should provide a function for that...